# How do I position an Admob Smart Banner?

Tags: ios, swift, admob

I created a 320x50 banner ad using this code:

```
var bannerView = GADBannerView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 20, 320, 50))
```

The ad should have y-position of 20 to leave a space for the status bar. Now, I would like to change to using a Smart Banner. So I changed my code to:

```
let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
```

Obviously the above code covers the status bar. I have no idea on how to make the Smart Banner appear at a y-position of 20.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `bannerView`'s `frame`:

```
let bannerView = GADBannerView(adSize: kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait)
bannerView.frame = CGRect(x: 0.0,
                          y: UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height,
                          width: bannerView.frame.width,
                          height: bannerView.frame.height)
```

Also, setting static positions is usually never a good idea. You can get the status bar's height with `UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height`. This way, if the status bar height ever changes you don't have to worry about it.

Answer (score 2):

You can initiate the view as below:

```
let bannerView = GADBannerView(frame:CGRectMake(0, UIApplication.sharedApplication().statusBarFrame.size.height, CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).width, CGSizeFromGADAdSize(kGADAdSizeSmartBannerPortrait).height))
```

Comment: `var` should be `let`.

Comment: @DanielStorm Thanks, I'm not that much familiar with swift.

Answer (score 0):

You can change your bannerview's frame like this:

```
 bannerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, bannerView.frame.width, bannerView.frame.height)
```